# SqlBulkCopy InvalidOperationException: The given value of type SqlDecimal from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy, sql-server-2019

I am running console app and using SqlBulkCopy to write records from a .NET DataTable to a MSSQL Database.

There is a column in the .NET: `new DataColumn(columnName, typeof(decimal));` that and one row has the value: 384.50000 in this field.

When the SqlBulkCopy is run (which is working fine on batches with smaller values) I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type SqlDecimal from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified target column. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type SqlDecimal from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified target column. ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter value '384.50000' is out of range.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata, Boolean isNull, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata, Boolean isNull, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)
```

The column that in the target database table is as follows:

```
,[Test_Column] DECIMAL(38,5) NULL
```

According to the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

`decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]` p (precision) The maximum total number of decimal digits to be stored. This number includes both the left and the right sides of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38.

Given that is the case, I can't see why I am getting the error:

`The given value of type SqlDecimal from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified target column. ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter value '384.50000' is out of range.`

Can anyone shed some light on how to solve this issue?

I have tried changing the db type to float to see if that would work, but when I am converting the values, that come from csv, to the .NET DataTable I can't loose the Exponential notation.  When it is decimal this works:

```
Decimal.Parse("-5E-05", NumberStyles.Float);    -0.00005    decimal
```

But when it is float this doesn't work:

```
(float)Decimal.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Float); -5E-05  float
```

Also it is prob worth mentioning that I have code that I am adding column mappings in SqlBulkCopy.  The CSV, .NET DataTable and DB table are all created from the same type definitions I use in .NET.  Eg; where it is a Decimal(38,5) in SQL it is a decimal in the .NET DataTable and the column names all match in the CSV, .NET Datatabe and DB table.

Environment:
MSSQL Server 2019 Developer Edition
Windows 10
C# console application .NET 4.7.2
Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Set the type of the DataTable column to SqlDecimal, and load each value with `new SqlDecimal(val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well turns out there was another column that had the wrong decimal precision assigned.
I was going to delete the question as it won't really help anyone as I was at fault, but was advised by SO not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual to use SqlDecimal in your DataTable.  Normally you use .NET primitives in a DataTable, so it would normally be Decimal, not SqlDecimal.

But I can't repro the behavior you describe.  EG

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SqlClientTest
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var constr = @"server=localhost;database=tempdb;Integrated Security=true";

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))

            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("create table #t(id int, val decimal(38,5))", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(SqlDecimal));

                var r = dt.Rows.Add();
                r["id"] = 1;
                r["val"] = new SqlDecimal(384.50000);

                using (var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "#t";

                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("id", "id"));
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("val", "val"));

                    bc.WriteToServer(dt);

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from #t", con);
                    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{r[0]} {r[1]}");
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using SqlDecimal but it still fails with the same error.  I am going to put together an demo project that replicates the issue now.  I will update the question with this.

Comment: So turns out there was another column, (my dataset had over 100 cols), that had DECIMAL(7,5) and had data that exceeded this.